# regex returning array undefined

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string through which I want to get desire data. I am using it in most of the functions and it is working fine, but I have develop another separate project and trying to use it but every time it is returning me array undefined.

My String is as follow which I get in data variable.

```
var data="<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
Dear Customer,<br>
<br>
We have assigned the following item to one of your employee.<br>
<br>
Item Number: 7372B456<br>
<br>
<strong>Basic Information</strong><br>
Cake type: 4 pounds<br>
Pickup time: Mon, Jan 2, 22:27 (GMT&#43;0500) PAK<br>
Pickup location: Riaz Uddin Ahmed Road - Karachi<br>
<strong>Driver assigned</strong><br>
Name: Imran Aziz<br>
Phone: 788888888888<br>
Baker: NEw horizon bakers<br>
<br>
If you need any help, please feel free to contact our hotline.<br>
<br>
Regards,<br>
<br>
Your Team
</body>
</html>";

var regEx = /\n|:(.*)</ig;
var match = regEx.exec(data);
```

But every time I get match undefined

Comment: What is the "desire data"?

Comment: @roydukkey every value after the sign of colon ":"

Comment: This cannot be done with the current input as it is not normalised. For example, ' 788888888888<br>' and ' Mon, Jan 2, 22:27 (GMT&#43;0500) PAK<br>' and '27 (GMT&#43;0500) PAK<br>' would all be matches based on your specification.

Answer (score 0):

To perform global match (all occurences), you should do it inside while loop.

```
   var regEx = /:(.*?)<br>/ig;
    while(match = regEx.exec(data)) {
    console.log(match[1]);
    }
```

Without loop, you got only first found value.

Also, changed (improved, imho) your regex a little - so target is now group [1]: https://regex101.com/r/U2rOa3/1

To see what was matched by your regex, check it on regex101. First matches are, of course, new lines...

```js
var data='<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"></head><body>Dear Customer,<br><br>We have assigned the following item to one of your employee.<br><br>Item Number: 7372B456<br><br><strong>Basic Information</strong><br>Cake type: 4 pounds<br>Pickup time: Mon, Jan 2, 22:27 (GMT&#43;0500) PAK<br>Pickup location: Riaz Uddin Ahmed Road - Karachi<br><strong>Driver assigned</strong><br>Name: Imran Aziz<br>Phone: 788888888888<br>Baker: NEw horizon bakers<br><br>If you need any help, please feel free to contact our hotline.<br><br>Regards,<br><br>Your Team</body></html>';

var regEx = /:(.*?)<br>/ig;
while(match = regEx.exec(data)) {
console.log(match[1]);
}
```